# ruby/bundler seeming to fail to derive dependencies

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I am getting this error when I run "bundle install"

```
Could not find gem 'febeling-rubyzip (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

My Gemfile looks like this

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

gem "authlogic", :git => "git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git"
gem "mechanize"
gem "hpricot"
gem "sqlite3-ruby"
gem "daemons"

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

gem "nokogiri"
gem "roo"
gem "zip"
gem "spreadsheet"
gem "builder"
gem "gimite-google-spreadsheet-ruby"
gem "febeling-rubyzip"

#gem "savon", "=0.7.9"
gem "savon"

#devise is required for rails_admin, but not used
gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'

gem 'febeling-rubyzip'

group :development, :test do
  gem "rcov"
  gem "capistrano"
end

group :development do
  gem "ruby-debug"
  gem "httpclient"
end
```

Any thoughts/tips would be greatly appreciarted.

Thanks, Chris

PS I am using rvm with per project gemsets.  Whats probably quite pertinent is that I just did a "rvm gemset empty" and remove Gemfile.lock to do a clean install of the project's gems - things seemed ok prior to that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace 'febeling-rubyzip' with 'rubyzip'. The new way of naming the gems has changed and it does not have the creator's username (github username) attached to it.

Comment: Many Thanks - that was it (and the google spreadsheet one too).

Answer (score 1):

Does `gem query -r -n febeling-rubyzip` find anything in your version of ruby/gems?

Comment: It says *** REMOTE GEMS *** then nothing :(

Comment: That's what I get too.  febeling-rubyzip is not a valid gem.  It looks like @andHapp's answer above should do the trick (just use `rubyzip` for your gem).